# When using react, the webpage is completely blank

Tags: reactjs, firebase, tsx

The webpage was being displayed prior to adding the firebase setDoc code. I have excluded the render tag, because when it is included I when adding in a render tag I am given an error stating  "cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element." This code is sending an option selected by a user using a radio button to firebase. Thanks in advance.

```
function RoleDecision(this: any) {
  let { user } = useUser();
  let { firestore } = useFirebase();

  let onValueChange = async (e: { target: { value: any } }) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  let formSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.selectedOption);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && firestore) {
      (async () => {
        setDoc(doc(firestore!, "users", `${user?.uid}`), {
          role: this.state.selectedOption,
        })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
          });
      })();
    }
  }, [firestore]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not use React class based and function based components simultaneously in the same file/component!**

My suggestion is to use function based only components, and to replace the `this.state` usage with `useState()` hook, the `onSubmit` and `onChange` events with proper handler functions like, `const onValueChange = (...) => {...}`